# Magento2, Adding Ids of Recent order in the customer dashboard navigation

Tags: magento2, admin, customer-account, navigation

I need to add recent orders of the customer in their dashboard navigation.

Currently i am able to locate how the navigation is created

> Magento_sales/layout/customer_account.xml

which uses

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order History</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

How can i display recent orders for customers in this navigations, under the Order History nav item